# Rails role_model with devise gives error "undefined method `roles_mask='"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, cancan, object-role-modeling

I have an app with devise. I installed the role_model and cancan gems. I updated the user.rb to read:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'role_model'

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :roles, :roles_mask

  include RoleModel

  roles_attribute :roles_mask

  roles :admin, :contributor, :guest
end
```

Then, in the rails console I try

```
> u = User.find(:first)
  User Load (1.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" LIMIT 1
 => #<User id: ...
> u.roles = [:admin]
NoMethodError: undefined method `roles_mask=' for #<User:0x00000002b57500>
    from /home/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails-3.2.11/gems/activemodel-3.2.11/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:407:in `method_missing'
```

Where does roles_mask come from? Do I need to include something else?

Answer (score 7):

In addition to installing the gems, the column `roles_mask` has to be added to the `users` table, as in this migration

```
class AddRolesMaskToUser < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :roles_mask, :integer
  end
end
```

This solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This question is not about Object Role Modeling (the modeling language). It's about how to model roles of objects, which is quite a different subject (the word Role has an entirely different meaning here).

On the other hand, if you want to combine Object Role Modeling with Rails, the Constellation Query Language (CQL) is a plain-text rendition of ORM, and also contains generators that target Rails.